# Graphing a Level Set in R

Tags: r

Any idea how to graph this equation in R? I've been requested to do this and don't know how to plot this with no numbers given.

```
p(x, y) = xy - max(.008x, .00075xy)
```

constraint:

```
x = exp(-y)/(1+exp(-y))
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: well you could create a fake datasets and try to plot it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define two functions like this:

```
#first you create the second equation i.e. x
f_x <- function(x) exp(-x)/(1+exp(-x))

#and then you rewrite the first function where you replace x with exp(-y)/(1+exp(-y))  
f_y <-  function(y) f_x(y) * y - max(.008 * f_x(y), .00075 * y * f_x(y))
```

And then plot it using `curve`:

```
curve(f_y)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Btw it seems right to me, but after I showed the graph to my coworker, he said max functions do not look like this, any ideas what he means? @LyzandeR

Comment: I suggest you ask them what they mean.

Comment: Yeah I think it's a completely different question he asked me, he wants me to make a graph based on a non-linear optimization problem. The original was the maximization function and the constraint is the equation below that. Thank you for your help @LyzandeR

Comment: I see. In any case, you are welcome, glad I could help :)